# Custom Search API Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, google-custom-search

Since September 5th, 2018 the custom search API dashboard screens no longer works.

I get no stats, no quotas for the project that I use. The service is still running from the front end, signing in with a personal account, other then the existing one I use, I find there is a new metrics section that has been added but that is not available to the other account?  The only work around is to into billing -> reports -> SKU for the current day to figure out what the quota usage is.  Is this a bug, or is there somewhere to upgrade the existing dashboard, new way to use the custom search, anyone else having this issue?

Comment: This is now fixed, google fixed the dashboard. As of Sunday the 9th, they didn't move anything it was busted, and they added there restricted service monitoring to the quota section. Was not aware Google developers would leave something that long as an issue, hence why I thought it was my issue. Still would have loved to have know where to go to see current list of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed, google fixed the dashboard. As of Sunday the 9th, they didn't move anything it was busted, and they added there restricted service monitoring to the quota section. Was not aware Google developers would leave something that long as an issue, hence why I thought it was my issue. Still would have loved to have know where to go to see current list of issues.